# UI automation to automate logging in to remote machine

Tags: automated-testing, uiautomation

I am trying to automate typing `Win` + `R`, and entering mstsc. This should open a Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) window. In the RDP window, I have to enter a host name. All these should be done using UI path.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You have the option to connect using a set of [commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc)

But if you want to use the UI for this or other Windows related apps, you can try [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/). Here is an example from the pywinauto docs:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
# Run a target application
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
# Select a menu item
app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Help->About Notepad")
# Click on a button
app.AboutNotepad.OK.click()
# Type a text string
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.type_keys("pywinauto Works!", with_spaces = True)
```

Comment: I think the main issue here is how to access controls within RDP screen.

Comment: @AlexeyR. yes. I am trying to use explore how to use UI path to automate a particular scenario which requires me to take a remote desktop connection.

Comment: [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html)